# Validate a GraphQL schema against another reference schema

Tags: validation, schema, graphql, specifications

I'm not quite sure the wording I should be searching for on this.

I have a GraphQL schema which wraps a group of services using `graphql-link-schema` to perform the data resolution on the client side. The schema is intended to be built against a separate reference schema. How can I programmatically validate that my implementation matches the reference?

For bonus points- is it possible to determine whether a schema is a superset of another?

Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting use case, but it's a bit unclear how validation like that would work. What causes validation to fail? Any differences between the two schemas? Extra types? Extra fields on existing types? Differences in return types? Differences in arguments or argument types?

Depending on your answer to the above questions, though, you may be able to cobble together your own validation function using the utility functions available [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/utilities/findBreakingChanges.js). Outside the main `findBreakingChanges` function, some of the utility functions available in that module:

```
findRemovedTypes
findTypesThatChangedKind
findFieldsThatChangedTypeOnObjectOrInterfaceTypes
findFieldsThatChangedTypeOnInputObjectTypes
findTypesRemovedFromUnions
findValuesRemovedFromEnums
findArgChanges
findInterfacesRemovedFromObjectTypes
```

If you have a reference or base schema available, though, rather than validating against it, you might also consider extending it when building the second schema. In doing so, you would effectively guarantee that the second schema matches the first except in whatever ways you intentionally deviate from it (by extending existing types, etc.). You could use [extendSchema](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/utilities/extendSchema.js) for relatively simply changes, or something like graphql-tool's [mergeSchemas](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching.html) for more complicated changes.

Comment: Nice. Yeah, those all look like promising avenues. "Validation" for me in this particular use-case means "fulfils all the functionality of the reference schema such that a client configured to talk to a reference system could talk to the implemented system with zero code changes". So extra types- no big deal. Extra fields on existing types- also not a big deal. Differences, though- those would be considered invalid.

Comment: I think it would be sufficient to just use `findBreakingChanges` in that case. That should effectively ensure any queries that were valid for the reference schema would still be valid if used with the second schema.

Comment: Nice, that sounds like the perfect tool for the job then. Great to know this is possible!